# solid line from a local average series

Tags: time-series

I have a time series of data taken from a meteorological station, and I have to extract values from it which are located on a precise point of time; problem is that the station time series I have only gives me average values of measures every half an hour. There is some method to get a smoth line from it, so I can take the singular values I need?

this drawing could explain it better: the black lines are the discrete values I have, the blue line is what I want. actually, it doesn't have to be necessarily smooth, it must be the most realistic it can, so it has to respect the average constraint; in other words, the expected value of taking a random point of the solid (blue) line should be the (black) local average value I have now.

[image]

if different options exist, and maybe some books explain them, I'd be happy if you tell me.

Answer (score 5):

What you want is a mean preserving interpolation. John D'Errico has the exact solution you're looking for, written in MATLAB however.

https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/31378

```
function [y,spl]=mean_series(ymeans,n,EndConditions)
% mean_series: cubic spline resampling of series in x
% (n times), maintaining the mean
%
% arguments:
% ymeans - vector of means
% n - 
% EndConditions - flag specifying natural or not-a-knot 
% end conditions on the spline. 
% EndConditions == 0 --> natural
% EndConditions == 1 (default) --> not-a-knot
%
% y - interpolated series, y has the property that:
% ymeans == sum(reshape(y,n,length(x)))
%
% spl - cubic spline as a piecewise cubic Hermite function

% ensure that ymeans is a column vector
ymeans=ymeans(:);
nmeans=length(ymeans);

% things will fail unless there are at least two
% points in ymeans
if nmeans<2
  error 'I require length(ymeans)>=2 or dire things will happen'
end

% nmeans+1 implicit knots
nk=nmeans+1;

% implicit positions of points supplied
xmeans=(0:(nmeans-1))';

% implicit positions of knots
knots=(0:nmeans)'-0.5;

% knot spacing
delta=diff(knots);

% implicit coordinates of the points to be predicted
% (interpolations at these points)
x=linspace(knots(1),knots(end),nmeans*n+1)';
x(end)=[];
ny=n*nmeans;

% define the spline as a piecewise cubic Hermite at
% the knots. This gives us nk function values and
% nk derivatives.

% Force the spline to be C2. compute the matrix
% relating function values to first derivatives,
% comes about from second derivative continuity at
% the knots. these will be equality constraints on
% the unknown spline coefficients.
feq=zeros(nk-2,nk);
deq=zeros(nk-2,nk);
rhseq=zeros(nk-2,1);
for i=2:(nk-1)
  j=i-1;
  feq(j,i+[-1 0 1])=-[-6/delta(j)^2 , ...
      (6/delta(j)^2)-(6/delta(i)^2) , 6/delta(i)^2];
  deq(j,i+[-1 0 1])=[2/delta(j) , ...
      4/delta(j)+4/delta(i) , 2/delta(i)];
end

% next, "evaluate" the points through the implicitly
% defined spline. We do not yet have the coefficients
% defining the spline, but we will eventually.
% k specifies which knot interval the points fall in.
k=repmat(1:nmeans,n,1);
k=k(:);

t=(x-knots(k))./delta(k);
t2=t.*t;
t3=t2.*t;
s2=(1-t).*(1-t);
s3=s2.*(1-t);

% build the matrix sparsely for efficiency, then convert
% the system to full since its really not sparse enough
% to save much.
fmat=[3*s2-2*s3 , 3*t2-2*t3];
dmat=[-delta(k).*(s3-s2) , delta(k).*(t3-t2)];
imat=(1:ny)';
imat=[imat,imat];
jmat=[k,k+1];

fmat0=full(sparse(imat,jmat,fmat,ny,nk));
dmat0=full(sparse(imat,jmat,dmat,ny,nk));

% now, compute implicit means of every n points.
% do it via a matrix multiply.
M=kron(eye(nmeans,nmeans),ones(1,n)/n);
fmat=M*fmat0;
dmat=M*dmat0;

% Since these means are to be forced, specify them
% as equality constraints, appending them to the set
% of equalities.
feq=[feq;fmat];
deq=[deq;dmat];
rhseq=[rhseq;ymeans];

% End condotions are either: 'natural', 'not-a-knot'
% test for default on EndConditions

switch EndConditions
 case 0
  % natural boundary conditions, i.e., zero second
  % derivative at ends
  fe=zeros(2,nk);
  de=zeros(2,nk);
  % at the bottom knot:
  fe(1,1:2)=[-1, 1]*6/(delta(1)^2);
  de(1,1:2)=[-2, -1]*2/delta(1);
  % at the top knot:
  fe(2,nk+[-1 0])=[1, -1]*6/(delta(nk-1)^2);
  de(2,nk+[-1 0])=[1, 2]*2/delta(nk-1);
  % append to equality constraints matrix
  feq=[feq;fe];
  deq=[deq;de];
  rhseq=[rhseq;zeros(2,1)];
case 1
  % not-a-knot end conditions, 3rd derivative continuity at
  % 2nd knot and next to last knots
  fe=zeros(1+(nk>3),nk);
  de=fe;
  % at the second knot:
  fe(1,1:3)=[1 -1 0]*12/(delta(1)^3)-[0 1 -1]*12/(delta(2)^3);
  de(1,1:3)=[1 1 0]*6/(delta(1)^2)-[0 1 1]*6/(delta(2)^2);
  % at the top knot:
  if nk>3
    fe(2,nk+(-2:0))=[1 -1 0]*12/(delta(nk-2)^3)- ...
         [0 1 -1]*12/(delta(nk-1)^3);
    de(2,nk+(-2:0))=[1 1 0]*6/(delta(nk-2)^2)- ...
         [0 1 1]*6/(delta(nk-1)^2);
  end
  % append to equality constraints matrix
  feq=[feq;fe];
  deq=[deq;de];
  rhseq=[rhseq;zeros(1+(nk>3),1)];
end

% the second derivative regularizer is a quadratic form of the form
% s'*regmat*s,
% where s is the vector of (unknown) second derivatives at the knots.
regmat=zeros(nk,nk);
regmat(1,1:2)=[delta(1)/3 , delta(1)/6];
regmat(nk,nk+[-1 0])=[delta(nk-1)/6 , delta(nk-1)/3];

for i=2:(nk-1)
  regmat(i,i+[-1 0 1])=[delta(i-1)/6 , (delta(i-1)+delta(i))/3 , delta(i)/6];
end

% next, write the second derivatives as a function of the
% function values and first derivatives: s = [sf,sd]*[f;d]
sf=zeros(nk,nk);
sd=zeros(nk,nk);
for i=1:(nk-1)
  sf(i,i+[0 1])=[-1 1].*(6/(delta(i)^2));
  sd(i,i+[0 1])=[-4 -2]./delta(i);
end
sf(nk,nk+[-1 0])=[1 -1].*(6/(delta(nk-1)^2));
sd(nk,nk+[-1 0])=[2 4]./delta(nk-1);

regmat=[sf,sd]'*regmat*[sf,sd];

% ensure numerical symmetry of the hessian
regmat=regmat+regmat';

% now, solve this whole mess of a linear system
% using a quadratic programming package.
% assume quadprog from the optimization toolbox 2.0
H=regmat;
f=zeros(2*nk,1);
Aeq=[feq,deq];
beq=rhseq;
options=optimset('quadprog');
coef=quadprog(H,f,[],[],Aeq,beq,[],[],[],options);

% break the coeficients up into a spline.
% first column is the knots, the second column 
% is function values at the knots, the third column
% is first derivatives at the knots.
spl=[knots,reshape(coef,nk,2)];

% return predictions at the original points
y=fmat0*spl(:,2)+dmat0*spl(:,3);
```

We can test out this function:

```
ymeans=sin(1:22)';
n=3;
EndConditions=1;

[yhat,spl]=mean_series(ymeans,n,1);

plot(yhat);
hold on
plot(kron(ymeans,ones(n,1)));
hold off
```

[image]

*Beautiful!!*

Here's yhat, reshaped so that the mean of each row will be equal to the original input:

```
>> reshape(yhat,3,22)'
ans =

    0.6038    0.8903    1.0303
    1.0413    0.9407    0.7459
    0.4743    0.1473   -0.1983
   -0.5214   -0.7848   -0.9642
   -1.0390   -0.9948   -0.8430
   -0.6010   -0.2903    0.0531
    0.3894    0.6811    0.9005
    1.0219    1.0263    0.9198
    0.7147    0.4279    0.0937
   -0.2493   -0.5639   -0.8188
   -0.9845   -1.0373   -0.9782
   -0.8141   -0.5570   -0.2387
    0.1042    0.4354    0.7210
    0.9276    1.0275    1.0167
    0.8968    0.6749    0.3792
    0.0434   -0.2981   -0.6090
   -0.8525   -0.9972   -1.0344
   -0.9610   -0.7792   -0.5128
   -0.1911    0.1548    0.4860
    0.7618    0.9471    1.0300
    1.0038    0.8673    0.6388
    0.3414   -0.0014   -0.3666
```

Let's make sure the mean was preserved for each set of n points:

```
>>yhat_means=kron(eye(length(ymeans)),repmat(1/n,1,n))*yhat;
>>[yhat_means,ymeans]

ans =

    0.8415    0.8415
    0.9093    0.9093
    0.1411    0.1411
   -0.7568   -0.7568
   -0.9589   -0.9589
   -0.2794   -0.2794
    0.6570    0.6570
    0.9894    0.9894
    0.4121    0.4121
   -0.5440   -0.5440
   -1.0000   -1.0000
   -0.5366   -0.5366
    0.4202    0.4202
    0.9906    0.9906
    0.6503    0.6503
   -0.2879   -0.2879
   -0.9614   -0.9614
   -0.7510   -0.7510
    0.1499    0.1499
    0.9129    0.9129
    0.8367    0.8367
   -0.0089   -0.0089
```

I think this code is extremely satisfying. I've tried to replicate it in R, but I have yet to find a QP solver that works well with equality constraints and no bounds (the Rcplex package might work, but you have to pay for it, which is dumb, since if you're paying for software, you'd pick MATLAB or some other software with decent support). The following R functions/packages that have QP solvers *do **NOT** work* for this problem (non-exclusive list): quadprog, ipop, ROI, auglag, nlminb, optimx, trust, COBYLA.

If anyone is interested in that R code, here it is, with one of the dumb solvers (if a good solver becomes available, you can just replace that line, and the code will work as well as the MATLAB implementation - and don't forget to leave a comment here if you find it):

```
library(alabama)
library(fBasics)

# identity matrix
eye<-function(n){
  if(n==0){
    return(matrix(0,0,0))
  }else{
    M<-matrix(0,n,n)
    M[1+0:(n-1)*(n+1)]<-1
    return(M)
  }
}

# function inspired by matlab's sparse()
sparse<-function(i,j,v,n=0,m=0,nz=0){
  S<-matrix(nz,max(max(i),n),max(max(j),m))
  S[cbind(matrix(i,ncol=1),matrix(j,ncol=1))]<-matrix(v,ncol=1)
  return(S)
}

mean_series<-function(ymeans,n,EndConditions=1,Method="L-BFGS-B"){
  # mean_series: cubic spline resampling of series in x
  # (n times), maintaining the mean
  #
  # arguments:
  # ymeans - vector of means
  # n - 
  # EndConditions - flag specifying natural or not-a-knot 
  # end conditions on the spline. 
  # EndConditions <-<- 0 --> natural
  # EndConditions <-<- 1 (default) --> not-a-knot
  #
  # y - interpolated series, y has the property that:
  # ymeans <-<- sum(reshape(y,n,length(x)))
  #
  # spl - cubic spline as a piecewise cubic Hermite function

  # ensure that ymeans is a column vector
  ymeans<-matrix(ymeans,ncol = 1)
  nmeans<-length(ymeans)

  # things will fail unless there are at least two
  # points in ymeans
  if (nmeans<2){
    stop('I require length(ymeans)><-2 or dire things will happen')
  }

  # nmeans+1 implicit knots
  nk<-nmeans+1

  # implicit positions of knots
  knots<-cbind(0:nmeans)-0.5

  # knot spacing
  delta<-diff(knots)

  # implicit coordinates of the points to be predicted
  # (interpolations at these points)
  x<-seq(knots[1],knots[length(knots)],length.out =nmeans*n+1)
  x<-cbind(x[-length(x)])
  ny<-n*nmeans

  # define the spline as a piecewise cubic Hermite at
  # the knots. This gives us nk function values and
  # nk derivatives.

  # Force the spline to be C2. compute the matrix
  # relating function values to first derivatives,
  # comes about from second derivative continuity at
  # the knots. these will be equality constraints on
  # the unknown spline coefficients.
  feq<-matrix(0,nk-2,nk)
  deq<-matrix(0,nk-2,nk)
  rhseq<-matrix(0,nk-2,1)
  for(i in 2:(nk-1)){
    j<-i-1
    feq[j,i+(-1:1)]<--cbind(-6/delta[j]^2 ,(6/delta[j]^2)-(6/delta[i]^2) , 6/delta[i]^2)
    deq[j,i+(-1:1)]<- cbind(2/delta[j] , 4/delta[j]+4/delta[i] , 2/delta[i])
  }

  # next, "evaluate" the points through the implicitly
  # defined spline. We do not yet have the coefficients
  # defining the spline, but we will eventually.
  # k specifies which knot interval the points fall in.
  k<-matrix(1:nmeans,n*nmeans,1)

  t<-(x-knots[k])/delta[k]
  t2<-t*t
  t3<-t2*t
  s2<-(1-t)*(1-t)
  s3<-s2*(1-t)

  # build the matrix sparsely for efficiency, then convert
  # the system to full since its really not sparse enough
  # to save much.
  fmat<-cbind(3*s2-2*s3 , 3*t2-2*t3)
  dmat<-cbind(-delta[k]*(s3-s2) , delta[k]*(t3-t2))
  imat<-cbind(1:ny)
  imat<-cbind(imat,imat)
  jmat<-cbind(k,k+1)

  fmat0<-sparse(imat,jmat,fmat,ny,nk)
  dmat0<-sparse(imat,jmat,dmat,ny,nk)

  # now, compute implicit means of every n points.
  # do it via a matrix multiply.
  M<-kron(eye(nmeans),matrix(1,1,n)/n)
  fmat<-M%*%fmat0
  dmat<-M%*%dmat0

  # Since these means are to be forced, specify them
  # as equality constraints, appending them to the set
  # of equalities.
  feq<-rbind(feq,fmat)
  deq<-rbind(deq,dmat)
  rhseq<-rbind(rhseq,ymeans)

  # End condotions are either: 'natural', 'not-a-knot'
  # test for default on EndConditions

  if(EndConditions==0){
    # natural boundary conditions, i.e., zero second
    # derivative at ends
    fe<-matrix(0,2,nk)
    de<-matrix(0,2,nk)
    # at the bottom knot:
    fe[1,1:2]<-c(-1, 1)*6/(delta[1]^2)
    de[1,1:2]<-c(-2, -1)*2/delta[1]
    # at the top knot:
    fe[2,nk+(-1:0)]<-c(1,-1)*6/(delta[nk-1]^2)
    de[2,nk+(-1:0)]<-c(1,2)*2/delta[nk-1]
    # append to equality constraints matrix
    feq<-rbind(feq,fe)
    deq<-rbind(deq,de)
    rhseq<-rbind(rhseq,matrix(0,2,1))
  }
  if(EndConditions==1){
    # not-a-knot end conditions, 3rd derivative continuity at
    # 2nd knot and next to last knots
    fe<-matrix(0,1+(nk>3),nk)
    de<-fe
    # at the second knot:
    fe[1,1:3]<-c(1,-1,0)*12/(delta[1]^3)-c(0,1,-1)*12/(delta[2]^3)
    de[1,1:3]<-c(1,1,0)*6/(delta[1]^2)-c(0,1,1)*6/(delta[2]^2)
    # at the top knot:
    if(nk>3){
      fe[2,nk+(-2:0)]<-c(1,-1,0)*12/(delta[nk-2]^3)-c(0,1,-1)*12/(delta[nk-1]^3)
      de[2,nk+(-2:0)]<-c(1,1,0)*6/(delta[nk-2]^2)-c(0,1,1)*6/(delta[nk-1]^2)
    }
    # append to equality constraints matrix
    feq<-rbind(feq,fe)
    deq<-rbind(deq,de)
    rhseq<-rbind(rhseq,matrix(0,1+(nk>3),1))
  }

  # the second derivative regularizer is a quadratic form of the form
  # s'*regmat*s,
  # where s is the vector of (unknown) second derivatives at the knots.
  regmat<-matrix(0,nk,nk)
  regmat[1,1:2]<-cbind(delta[1]/3 , delta[1]/6)
  regmat[nk,nk+(-1:0)]<-cbind(delta[nk-1]/6 , delta[nk-1]/3)

  for(i in 2:(nk-1)){
    regmat[i,i+(-1:1)]<-c(delta[i-1]/6 , (delta[i-1]+delta[i])/3 , delta[i]/6)
  }

  # next, write the second derivatives as a function of the
  # function values and first derivatives: s <- [sf,sd]*[fd]
  sf<-matrix(0,nk,nk)
  sd<-matrix(0,nk,nk)
  for(i in 1:(nk-1)){
    sf[i,i+(0:1)]<-c(-1,1)*(6/(delta[i]^2))
    sd[i,i+(0:1)]<-c(-4,-2)/delta[i]
  }
  sf[nk,nk+(-1:0)]<-c(1,-1)*(6/(delta[nk-1]^2))
  sd[nk,nk+(-1:0)]<-c(2,4)/delta[nk-1]

  regmat<-t(cbind(sf,sd))%*%regmat%*%cbind(sf,sd)

  # ensure numerical symmetry of the hessian
  regmat<-regmat+t(regmat)

  # now, solve this whole mess of a linear system
  # using a quadratic programming package.
  # assume quadprog from the optimization toolbox 2.0
  H<-regmat
  f<-matrix(0,2*nk,1)
  Aeq<-cbind(feq,deq)
  beq<-rhseq


  # THIS QP SOLVER DOESN'T FREAKIN WORK AT ALL.
  coef<-cbind(auglag(cbind(rep(0,dim(H)[1])),
                     fn=function(x){t(x)%*%H%*%x},
                     hin=function(x){Aeq%*%x-beq}, 
                     hin.jac=function(x){Aeq}, 
                     heq=function(x){1}, 
                     heq.jac=function(x){rbind(rep(0,dim(Aeq)[2]))},
                     control.outer = list(method=Method,trace=FALSE,itmax=100))$par)



  # break the coeficients up into a spline.
  # first column is the knots, the second column 
  # is function values at the knots, the third column
  # is first derivatives at the knots.
  spl<-cbind(knots,matrix(coef,nk,2))

  # return predictions at the original points
  y<-fmat0%*%spl[,2]+dmat0%*%spl[,3]
  return(y)
}
```

Let's test this stupid QP solver to see how absolutely useless it is:

```
ymeans<-sin(1:22)
n<-3
yhat<-mean_series(ymeans,n)

lineplot(cbind(kron(ymeans,cbind(rep(1,n))),yhat),1:66,legend = FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you very much! it will take me a lot to undertand all this, it's quite different from any solution I was expecting

Answer (score 0):

I think there are a number of methods that suit what you're looking for - some options are:
 1. kernel smoothing
 2. spline smoothing
 3. moving average

There are many more, but I think those three are good candidates. [Here](http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/19055_69871309d9e0495b9663bb14afe93a07.html) is a very nice visual explanation of several smoothing techniques.

The problem is that technically, between $t_a$ and $t_b$, the temperature could take on any value on your measurement scale. Fortunately, since we can probably assume at least moderate time-dependence, the temp at $t_b$ should at be at least partially related to the temp at $t_a$. Choosing a good smoothing method and parameters depends on how strong you think the time dependent effects are, how smooth you want your smoothing function to be, how variable you think think the temp is during the unobserved period.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! Fact is, this is not answering my problem: I don't simply need to smooth some data, not caring if my curve will touch or not the previous points, I need a curve that, if my series has a maximum, pass over it and then comes back down (you can see what I'm talking about in the graph I drew), a curve created with a smoothing technique would pass under the maximum, keeping its distance.